# What does 'pc = pc+4+BranchAddr' mean?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I was doing this question:

The following instruction is not included in the MIPS instruction set:
rpt $t2, loop # if(R[rs]>0) R[rs]=R[rs]−1, PC=PC+4+BranchAddr
(note, BranchAddr is the encoded value that is used to calculate target “loop” address)

So what does the PC=PC+4+BranchAddr mean?

Comment: It means to update the program counter with a relative displacement, like other MIPS branch instructions.

Comment: could you be more specific? I am so bad at assembly code stuff